# { % include tag %} including only one object from another template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

guys i need a small help 
here is my views.py

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        verification=VerificationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            userObj = form.cleaned_data
            username = userObj['username']
            email =  userObj['email']
            password =  userObj['password']
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/verification/')
            # if
            if not (User.objects.filter(username=username).exists() or User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()):
                User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
                user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Looks like a username with that email or password already exists')
        else:

            raise forms.ValidationError('a valid')

    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
        verification = VerificationForm()

    return render(request, 'question/signup.html',context= {'verification':verification,'form' : form})
```

here you can see i have declared two context variables one is form and the other one is verification now  i want to use 
now this is my signup.html

```
{% extends 'question/index.html '%}

{% block body_block %}
<div class="conrainer">


  <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook'%}">facebook auth</a>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

now i have used form variable in this page
and i want to use verification varible  in another page as django views are not made to use two templates in a single view
after searching a lot in online forums i came to know about {% include tag %}
after trying to use that tag after going through documentation 
this is how my verification.html is

```
{% include 'question/signup.html' with obj=verification only%}
<div class="container">

<form  method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<p>{{verification.as_p}}</p>
<p>{{obj.as_p}}</p>




<input type="submit" name="verify" value="" action='.' align='center'name='submit'>
</form>
</div>
```

here is my urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^/',views.home,name='home'),
    url(r'^home/',Home,name='home'),
    url(r'^ques/',Create.as_view(success_url="/index/home/"),name='ques'),
    url(r'^signup/',signup,name='signup'),
    # url(r'^signup/',MyFormView.as_view(),name='signup'),
    url(r'^verification/',TemplateView.as_view(template_name="question/verification.html")),

    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout,name='logout'),
    url(r'^search/',Search,name='search'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

    # url(r'^verify/',verificationView,name='signup'),


    # CreateView.as_view(model=myModel, success_url=reverse('success-url'))

]
```

but after trying it so many ways   either obj or verification shows up in the site  is there any way where i can only get the context object instead of getting the subit button and all from my signup.html using INCLUDE  any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: You return a redirect response from the middle of your code! You might also show your urls. I assume the view behind `'/index/verification/'` lacks those context variables.

Comment: @schwobaseggl urls.py has been  added  and  if possible could you tell me any way to make my context variables show up in my site

Comment: `return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/verification/')` end processing and returns a redirect - the code below it is never executed

Comment: ok bro is there any way where we can run  the page redirection process and get the data from the other site and execute the below code ,if possible